# Why does this use sometimes the E arpeggio and sometimes the Em arpeggio?

Tags: harmony, modulation

The song Tornado of Souls by Megadeth is in the key of Bm. The solo plays over a progression of power chords that goes B5 - G5 - E5 - F#5 - A5. Over the E5, the solo first plays an Em arpeggio but then changes to E major. What's the theory behind this? I don't *think* they meant it as a dorian thing, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I don't know the etiquette around posting links to Spotify, so I'll leave it as a comment (easier to delete if it's not acceptable): https://open.spotify.com/track/4E5xVW505akJX0wcKj8Mpd - at 3:08

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a trick used in music. It's called using the parallel key. Chords (and notes) from E major can and are used as alternates to E minor and its chords/notes. Since the chords used are known as 5s, with no major or minor third, solo notes can be from major and/or minjor, since there's nothing to clash.